# Regression with variable known uncertainty with GPFlow

Tags: regression, gpflow

I am trying to model some 1D data where each data point has a different error bar.

In the GPFlow documentation I find an example of how to do this here ([known noise variances demo](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/develop/notebooks/advanced/varying_noise.html#Demo-1:-known-noise-variances))

However, the demo doesn't seem to produce a GP model that models the data well and I was wondering if anyone had any suggests to improve the GP fit in the demo?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your problem and what is not working for you? Posting a snippet to reproduce the issue would help a lot. Thanks

Comment: This was actually a bug in the notebook example, which is fixed [by this PR](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/pull/1526). This question itself should probably be closed/deleted, or if you still have issues please clarify your question!

Comment: Thanks for the replies and thanks for the PR! I will close this for now and give the PR ago when it's merged.

Comment: @cyberface is this ready to close? the PR is merged

Comment: @joel yeah it's working! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/pull/1526). It was a typo in the documentation.